# NoSuchMethodError after migration to Android Studio 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Afer installing the new Android Studio RC2 I receive this exception in the console and when sync with IDE.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':[ProjectName]:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug'.

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.write(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V
```

I've actualized 'compile' to 'implementation' and 'testCompile' to 'testImplementation', libs and plugins are updated as well

com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-rc2

buildToolsVersion '26.1.0'

Comment: You sure that you used `buildToolsVersion` in RC 2?

Comment: Yes, I' am sure! buildToolsVersion  '26.0.2'

Comment: you can remove it in AS RC now.

Comment: @Ibrahim what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

After searching for solution and try a lot of tips, nothing worked. Only when I've updated **gradle wrapper from 4.1 to 4.2.1**, the problem disappear. I hope this fix work for you!